Spring Flux Stream HeartBeat Async Exception
I have a controller that looks like this:
@RestController
public class MyController {

    private final Flux<T> flux1;
    private final Flux<T> flux2;

    @GetMapping(produces = APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<T> subscribe() {

        var mergedFlux = Flux.merge(this.flux1, this.flux2).doOnCancel(() -> {
            log.debug("canceled");
        }).doOnError(e -> {
            log.error("error", e);
        });

        return keepAlive(Duration.of(10, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);, mergedFlux);
    }

    private Flux<T> keepAlive(Duration interval, Flux<T> flux) {
        Flux<HeartBeat> heartBeat = Flux.interval(interval)
                .map(t -> new HeartBeat()).doFinally(signalType -> log.debug("HearBeat 
closed"));
        return Flux.merge(flux, heartBeat);
    }
}

The problem is, whenever i close the connection of the client and the next HeartBeat would have been sent, i am getting the following exception:
Exception in thread "AsyncExecutor-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: A non-container (application) thread attempted to use the AsyncContext after an error had occurred and the call to AsyncListener.onError() had returned. This is not allowed to avoid race conditions
My config looks like this:
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.setTaskExecutor(poolTaskExecutor());
}

@Bean(name = "AsyncExecutor")
public AsyncTaskExecutor poolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncExecutor-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}

This only happens when i use the keepAlive method to send heartBeats inbetween to let the connection stay open and not run into a timeout.
How can i prevent this?
I am using Spring Web MVC and not Spring Webflux.
This is my setup of the sinks and flux:
@Configuration
public class SinkConfig {

    @Bean
    public Sinks.Many<T> flux1() {
        return Sinks.many().replay().latest();
    }

    @Bean
    public Flux<T> flux1(Sinks.Many<T> sink) {
        return sink.asFlux();
    }

    @Bean
    public Sinks.Many<T> flux2() {
        return Sinks.many().replay().latest();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Flux<T> flux2(Sinks.Many<T> sink) {
        return sink.asFlux();
    }
}


I will suggest to use onErrorResume or onErrorReturn to emit a captured fallback value when an error of the specified type is observed on this Flux. This way, if an error occurs, you can return a fallback value or an empty stream, preventing further processing that could lead to exceptions.
var mergedFlux = Flux.merge(this.flux1, this.flux2)
     .doOnCancel(() -> log.debug("canceled"))
     .doOnError(e -> log.error("error", e))
     .onErrorResume(e -> Flux.empty());

And also make sure that the keep-alive mechanism does not attempt to emit heartbeats after the original Flux has completed or errored out. You might want to use a takeUntil or similar operator to control the lifecycle of the heartbeats.
private Flux<T> keepAlive(Duration interval, Flux<T> flux) {
    Flux<HeartBeat> heartBeat = Flux.interval(interval)
            .map(t -> new HeartBeat())
            .doFinally(signalType -> log.debug("HeartBeat closed"));
    return Flux.merge(flux, heartBeat).takeUntil(flux);
}


what would be the correct way to check if the original flux has completed or errored? I tried it with takeUntil and check if the original flux is null, but that still leaves the error.

have u used onErrorResume @Bioaim ?

yes i have, i updated the question to add the flux configs, if it is relevant.

could the problem be, that i use Tomcat and not a Netty server?
